# Сохранение в JsonUtility

Tags: c#, unity3d, сериализация

### Описание

Создал у себя такой класс:

```cs
public class Homework
{
    public DateTime Date;
    public string Title, Description;
}
```

Сериализовал с помощью атрибута `System.Serializable`, создал список из этого класса и сохранил с помощью JSON.

```cs
PlayerPrefs.SetString("Homeworks", JsonUtility.ToJson(new Container(Data)))
```

...где `Container` класс, который содержит в себе список из классов `Homework`.

```cs
private class Container
{
    public List<Homework> Homeworks;
    public Container(List<Homework> Input)
    {
        Homeworks = Input;
    }
}
```

Сохраняется всё кроме поля `Date` (предполагаю что оно не сериализовано), но так как эта структура создано не мною, атрибут `System.Serializable` не помогает.

### Дополнение

Поискал в интернете `Как сериализовать системную структуру`. Результаты только о том как сериализовать собственную структуру.

---

*Тогда как мне сериализовать структуру `DateTime` или же если это невозможно то как сохранить поле `Date`?*

Comment: Чем вы сериализируете?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вот так `[System.Serializable]
 public class Homework{...}`

Comment: Это не сериализация, это просто класс с атрибутом. Вопрос тот же, чем вы преобразовываете  JSON?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `JsonUtility.ToJson(new Container(Data))` где `Container` класс который содержит в себе список из классов `Homework`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ сохранение происходит с помощью функций Unity - `PlayerPrefs.SetString("Homeworks", JsonUtility.ToJson(new Container(Data)))`. Я был не уверен: добавить тег `Unity` или нет, так как вопрос не совсем связан с Unity.

Comment: Unity что ли? А тег где...? Хорошо, скажу в пару словах: Парсер JSON в Unity полное ***. Настоятельно рекомендую вам обзавестись нормальным конвертором, например JSON.NET, который есть в магазине ассетов. Недавно был вопрос, где выяснилось, что JsonUtility не может даже простой словарь нормально преобразовать без танцев с бубнами. По поводу даты - [нашел такое](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/137523/unity-json-utility-does-not-serialize-datetime), как видите опять танцы с бубнами, пробуйте...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Посмотрю ваш совет но на данный момент мне надо быстрее закончить этот проект. А тег добавил.

Comment: Перейти на JSON.NET не составит труда. Ну а так, я вам решение дал, дерзайте, раз не хотите себе жизнь облегчить.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо за `Newtonsoft.Json`. Хоть закончил проект с достоинством. Перепишите ваш комментарий как ответ. Оно спасёт много жизней. ;-) Если надо могу и код прикрепить.

Comment: Это я оставляю на вас, то, что у вас получилось кидайте в ответ, составляйте его, я не против)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ дан участником [<kbd>**EvgeniyZ**</kbd>](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220553/evgeniyz)

---

Жить станет намного легче если для этой цели использовать библиотеку [<kbd>**Newtonsoft.Json**</kbd>](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347). Разницу вы сразу же заметите на примере...

---

### До

Чтобы сохранить / загрузить всё это мы используем различные фокусы, причём структура `Date` так и не будет сохранится:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Global: MonoBehaviour
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Homework
    {
        public DateTime Date;
        public string Title, Description;
    }

    private class Container
    {
        public List<Homework> Homeworks;
        public Container(List<Homework> Input)
        {
            Homeworks = Input;
        }
    }

    public static class Homeworks
    {
        public static List<Homework> Data = new List<Homework>();
        private static readonly string DataPath = "data";
        public static void Save()
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(DataPath, JsonUtility.ToJson(new Container(Data)));
        }
        public static void Load()
        {
            if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(DataPath))
            {
                Data = new List<Homework>();
            }
            else
            {
                Data = JsonUtility.FromJson<Container>(PlayerPrefs.GetString(DataPath)).Homeworks;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### После

Теперь всё это ясно и коротко с помощью Json.Net:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Global: MonoBehaviour
{
    public class Homework
    {
        public DateTime Date;
        public string Title, Description;
    }

    public static class Homeworks
    {
        public static List<Homework> Data = new List<Homework>();
        private static readonly string DataPath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "data.json");
        private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        };
        public static void Save()
        {
            File.WriteAllText(DataPath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, Settings));
        }
        public static void Load()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(DataPath))
            {
                Data = new List<Homework>();
            }
            else
            {
                Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Homework>>(File.ReadAllText(DataPath));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Плюсы библиотеки

- Сохраняется абсолютно всё
- Без сериализации
- Без лишних классов такие как `Container`
- Маленький размер (1.4 мб)