# Прочитать с JSON файла объекты, которые наследуются от абстрактного класса в Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

Есть абстрактный класс `EnemyAttackDATA` и три дочерних класса: `Bite`, `Fist`, `ZapBall`

Хочу, чтобы при чтении файла JSON объект типа `EnemyAttackDATA` преобразовывался к нужному типу, так как происходит здесь:

```cs
EnemyAttackDATA e1 = new Bite();
Debug.Log(e1.GetType()); // Bite
e1 = new Fist();
Debug.Log(e1.GetType()); // Fist
```

Я использую JsonUtility

**UPD:**
Насчет моей проблемы, то во-первых:
Ни JsonUtility от Unity, ни другие классы для чтения JSON не позволяют это:

`EnemyAttackDATA e = JsonUtility.FromJson<EnemyAttackDATA>(path)` т.к. `EnemyAttackDATA` - абстрактный класс

Во-вторых мне нужно, чтобы `JsonUtility` сам понимал, какой класс хранится в JSON и возвращал объект типа `Bite`, `Fist`, `ZapBall` в зависимости от того, что хранится в JSON

Comment: Просто `JsonUtility` от Юнити настолько кривая конструкция. Я не знаю в чём ваша проблема, но крайне не рекомендую её вообще использовать. Используйте лучше [JsonSerializer](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.5.php) встроенный в C#. Я когда-то тоже использовал `JsonUtility` и вот [с чем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1127429/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-jsonutility/1127716#1127716) столкнулся.

Comment: @Арман, за совет спасибо, правда я уже и сам это понял, и сейчес ищу альтернативу через JsonSerializer

Comment: еще очень мощный и хороший инструмент, проверенный на многих проектах и хорошо поддерживаемый [Newtonsoft json](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во время сериализации:

```cs
 JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
 {
     TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
 };
 string tojson = JsonConvert.Serialize(json, settings);

 File.WriteAllText("file.json", json);
```

Теперь в файле json указан тип:

```
{
"$type":"Bite, Assembly CSharp",
"Coeficient":1.0,
"Name":"Bite",
"Description":"",
"TimeToActivate":0.0,
"SizeOfCollider":0.0,
"Speed":0.0
}
```

Во время десериализации:

```cs
EnemyAttackDATA enemy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EnemyAttackDATA>(json, settings); //те же настройки
Debug.Log(enemy.GetType()); //Bite
```

Я использовал `Newtonsoft.Json` dll

Comment: если сами ответили на свой вопрос, то пометьте ответ как правильный и тем самым закройте вопрос в виду его неактуальности

Comment: Я просто забыл про него)